# Need to fix tile that has fallen off

Tags: tile, kitchen-counters, ceramic-tile

I have some tile in my kitchen that has fallen off (unglued I suppose). See pictures below. How do I fix this?  Recommendations for a novice DIYer?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend heavy duty constructive adhesive followed by grout colored caulk that best matche the grout around the tiles https://www.google.com/search?q=grout+colored+caulk

to minimize cost and work I would risk using the caulk as glue

1. try to remove the old adhesive
2. clean back of tile and wall well
3. put a lot of construction adhesive on the back of the tile (risky optional: replace construction adhesive with caulk)
4. put tile back on the wall and hold in place with masking/painter tape
5. 1  hour later remove tape
6. caulk around the tile and clean any thing that doesn't look neat with your fingers

Answer (score 3):

Get a fine sander/ grinder. Carefully remove adhesive from back of tile. Apply tile adhesive (available from hardware store) to the back of the tile. Put the tile back where it fell from. Hold the tile until you can remove your hand without it falling off or you can put something heavy against it to hold it in place.

Comment: Tile adhesive (mastic) or any heavy-duty construction or project adhesive.

Comment: @isherwood I did not understand your comment.  Are you suggesting something different from a tile adhesive?

Comment: Yes. No need to buy tile mortar if something like Liquid Nails is on hand.